# The sefer "Radiance of Shabbat" by Simcha Bunim Cohen on whether stam yeinam is ok for kiddush b'dieved

Tags: kiddush, stam-yenam

"Stam yeinam, which is wine processed or even possibly touched by a non-Jew or a public desecrator of Shabbat, is forbidden to be benefited from, and thus is obviously inappropriate for kiddush (YD 123:3, and Shakh 123:7). Poskim dispute whether one has fulfilled one's obligation if such wine was in fact used for kiddush." (Radiance of Shabbat, p. 47, note 21).

If anyone has this sefer, can they please tell me if the author says anything else about this, or if he quotes those "poskim" further, because it is a chiddush to me that stam yeinam would be good for kiddush even b'dieved.

Comment: How are you quoting it verbatim if you don't have access to it

Comment: This is probably relevant to the issue if an issur derabbanan can undo a mitzvah doraisa, assuming he means the biblical obligation of kiddush

Comment: @robev There is no biblical obligation to use wine for kiddush

Comment: @JoelK and...? Also the Aruch HaShulchan disagrees as he rules like the Ran (to be specific, he rules you need kiddush with some sort of food/drink, and Chazal chose wine)

Comment: @robev. If the need for wine is not biblical, then this is unlikely to be dependent on the question of whether an issur derabanan can undo a mitzvah deoraita. It’s unlikely to be worse than not using any wine at all.

Comment: @robev Also I don’t think AH rules like Ran. At least not explicitly. He quotes all the relevant opinions, and then adds what he thinks is a proof to Ran’s view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footnote you mentioned quotes the following opinions as ruling that *bediavad* one fulfills *kiddush* if one used *stam yeinam*:

- Responsa Kochav MiYaakov 198
- Responsa Chesed LeAvraham vol II 31
- Machazeh Avraham 49.

In contrast, the following opinions are quoting as ruling that even *bediavad* one has not fulfilled his obligation:

- Responsa Levushei Mordechai Orach Chaim 35
- Responsa Minchat Elazar vol II 18.

Finally, an oral opinion of R. CP Steinberg is quoted as ruling in consonance with the lenient opinions.